# Testing Django w/ DRF: issues defining a base test class for multiple test cases to inherit

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I'm working on a Django app that exposes an API with the help of Django REST Framework (DRF). I've gotten to the point where I need to create a testing framework and have been poring over both the DRF and Django testing docs.

I've defined a `BaseTestCase` class that sets up basic required data needed for all other test cases, as well as a `ModelTestCase` class that inherits from `BaseTestCase`, in order to make use of the setup performed. Here's how those look right now:

**BaseTestCase**

```
class BaseTestCase(APITestCase):
  '''
  This class does basic data setup required to test API endpoints
  Creates 1+ users, sets the client to use that user for auth
  '''

  @classmethod
  def create_data(cls):
    '''
    Create the users needed by automated tests
    '''
    # creates some data used by child test cases            

  @classmethod
  def setUpClass(cls):
    client = APIClient()
    cls.client = client
    # call the method to create necessary base data
    cls.create_data()
    # get a user and set the client to use their auth
    user = get_user_model().objects.get(email='auto-test@test.com')
    client.force_authenticate(user=user)
    # cls.client = client
    super(BaseTestCase, cls).setUpClass()

  def test_base_data(self):
    '''
    This test ensures base data has been created
    '''
    # tests basic data to ensure it's created properly

  def test_get_users(self):
    '''
    This test attempts to get the list of users via the API
    It depends on the class setup being complete and correct
    '''
    url = '/api/users/'
    response = BaseTestCase.client.get(url, format='json')
    print(json.loads(response.content))
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

**ModelTestCase**

```
class ModelTestCase(BaseTestCase):
  @classmethod
  def setUpClass(cls):
    super(ModelTestCase, cls).setUpClass()
    client = APIClient()
    user = get_user_model().objects.all()[0]
    client.force_authenticate(user=user)
    cls.client = client

  def test_create_model(self):
    '''
    Make sure we can create a new model with the API
    '''
    url = '/api/model/'
    # set the request payload
    response = ModelTestCase.client.post(url, data, format='json')
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

When I run all tests, I get a failure because one of the `BaseTestCase` data verification asserts (based on a count of how many objects are present) fails due to there being too many (since the `BaseTestCase` has been set up twice- once on it's own, once as part of the `setUpClass` of `ModelTestCase`

When I run *only* the `ModelTestCase`, I get the following error:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_get_users (app.tests.ModelTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/tests.py", line 125, in test_get_users
    response = BaseTestCase.client.get(url, format='json')
AttributeError: type object 'BaseTestCase' has no attribute 'client'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Which I don't understand- shouldn't the `setUpClass()` of `BaseTestCase` be running as normal?

I've also tried defining the `ModelTestCase` to inherit from `APITestCase`- with this configuration, running all tests succeeds, but (I believe) only because tests are run alphabetically, so the `BaseTestCase` runs, sets up data, and then the `ModelTestCase` can make use of that data.

I'd like for the tests themselves to be independent- and I believe `setUpData()` can be used for that. However, I also want the client setup (for auth) as well as data setup (which will end up being relatively expensive, I think) to be shared across test cases so that it wouldn't need to be repeated per-case, which is why I thought creating a base class to inherit from was the way to go.

Is there a way to accomplish what I've outlined? Should I be using `setUpData()` instead of `setUpClass()`? Or is there a way to create my `BaseTestCase` class and have it *not* run when tests are executed?

Answer (score 0):

According to Django Rest Framework Testing section, you should keep the default schema using `setUp()` methods. That's how I've found a resonable solution:

```
from django.urls import reverse
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase
import pytest

from core.factories import UserFactory, ClientFactory, AdministratorFactory, FacilitatorFactory, ParticipantFactory 


class BaseAPITestCase(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.user = UserFactory()
        self.client.force_authenticate(user=self.user)


class UserTestCase(BaseAPITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # Call Parent's constructor.
        super(self.__class__, self).setUp()
        self.clients = ClientFactory(user=self.user)
        self.administrator = AdministratorFactory(user=self.user)
        self.facilitator = FacilitatorFactory(user=self.user)
        self.participant = ParticipantFactory(user=self.user)

    def test_get_users(self):
        url = reverse("api_v1:user-list")
        response = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertEquals(response.data["count"], 1)
        self.assertEquals(response.data["results"][0]["username"], self.user.username)
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)
```

Result:

```
============================================================================== test session starts ===============================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.7.6, pytest-5.3.0, py-1.8.1, pluggy-0.13.1 -- 
cachedir: .pytest_cache
Django settings: tests.settings (from ini file)
Using --randomly-seed=1589794116
plugins: django-3.7.0, django-test-migrations-0.1.0, randomly-3.1.0, hypothesis-4.53.0, timeout-1.3.0, testmon-1.0.0, cov-2.8.0, deadfixtures-2.1.0
collected 1 items                                                                                                                                                               

tests/api/test_basics.py::UserTestCase::test_get_users PASSED
```